# What is the most energy efficient source of electrons?

Tags: electricity, electrons

Wanting to build a cathode ray tube, and I see there are a few electron sources such as thermionic emission and field electron emission. Since my project is small scale, since I don't want to go to the hospital dealing with high voltages, and since efficiency I was just wondering which of the methods of electron generation is most energy efficient.

Comment: The other danger with high voltages is x-ray generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field emission does not require energy.

Thermionic emission depends on high temperature of the source so one needs some energy for that (typically/traditionally 6.3 volt AC). Any incandescent filament will give thermionic emission, but if you need low energy spread you want to use indirectly heated cathodes. A barium coating will enhance the current.

Comment: I'd guess for a 'small scale' project the energy spread won't be an issue - the classic hot filament is the way to go given the billions of vacuum tubes produced over the years.

Comment: @JonCuster The classic vacuum tubes (especially those for audio applications) used to have indirectly heated cathodes to prevent modulation by the ac current (hum). I agree that OP does not sound like that this would be an issue, so the simplest solution might be to take an old-fashioned bicycle light and crush the glass bulb.